# Building 32-bit Detours library

Tags: 32-bit, nmake, detours

I'm using Detours library from microsoft, and I was using the 32bit version (which is free). I'm now on a 64-bit installation of windows 7 and I can't seem to compile Detours with nmake.

Here is the error:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 9.00.21022.08
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Detours Express 2.1\src"
Building for 64-bit X64.
        if not exist "..\include" mkdir "..\include"
        if not exist "..\lib" mkdir "..\lib"
        if not exist "..\bin" mkdir "..\bin"
        cl /LD /nologo /W4 /WX /Zi /MTd /Gy /Gm- /Zl /O1 /DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN /
D_WIN32_WINNT=0x403 /D_WIN64 /DDETOURS_X64=1 /D_AMD64_ /Wp64 /Fe..\bin\detoured.
dll /Fd..\bin\detoured.pdb detoured.cpp  /link /release /machine:amd64 /base:0xf
000000 /incremental:no /subsystem:console  /entry:DllMain /implib:..\lib\detoure
d.lib  /export:Detoured kernel32.lib detoured.res
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'Wp64' has been deprecated and will be
removed in a future release
detoured.cpp
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourc
eannotations.h(17) : error C2371: 'size_t' : redefinition; different basic types

        detoured.cpp : see declaration of 'size_t'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\basetsd.h(305) : warning C
4311: 'type cast' : pointer truncation from 'const void *' to 'unsigned long'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\basetsd.h(314) : warning C
4311: 'type cast' : pointer truncation from 'const void *' to 'long'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\basetsd.h(323) : warning C
4312: 'type cast' : conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'void *' of greater size
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winnt.h(12935) : error C38
61: '__readfsdword': identifier not found
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\
VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\
VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

As you see, it's trying to compile for 64-bit. How can I force nmake to build for 32bits?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed windows SDK to compile. Simply google windfows SDK, download & install, run the Windows SDK console in admin mode and compile!

If installing SDK on windows 7 gives errors, here is the solution:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2717426/de

> This issue occurs when you install the Windows 7 SDK on a computer that has a newer version of the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable installed.  The Windows 7 SDK installs version 10.0.30319 of the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable.
>
> To resolve this issue, you must uninstall all versions of the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable before installing the Windows 7 SDK.  You may have one or more of the following products installed:

- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable

Answer (score 3):

Next time, simply set the DETOURS_TARGET_PROCESSOR environment variable. Valid values are x86, AMD64 and IA64. (The Express version of Detours only supports x86.)